# PHP Formatting while loading into a view

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am loading a data into view from a library but the output obtained is not formatted i need the formatted output, how can i achieve that?

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
echo '<title>'.$seo_data[0]->META_TITLE.'</title>'
        .'<meta name="description" content="'.$seo_data[0]->META_DESCRIPTION.'" />'
        .'<meta name="keywords" content="'.$seo_data[0]->META_KEYWORDS.'" />'
        .'<meta name="url" content="'.$seo_data[0]->META_URL.'" />'
        .'<meta name="copyright" content="'.$seo_data[0]->META_COPYRIGHT.'" />';
```

**what i got Output Obtained**

```
<title>Test</title><meta name="description" content="Test." /><meta name="keywords" content="Test" /><meta name="url" content="Test" /><meta name="copyright" content="Test" />
```

**This is the Required Output**

```
<title>Test</title>
<meta name="description" content="Test." />
<meta name="keywords" content="Test" />
<meta name="url" content="Test" />
<meta name="copyright" content="Test" />
```

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Comment: sorry for late @pradeep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Use CI `html helper` instead of traditional way , load html helper in `autoload.php` like this

```
$autoload['helper'] =array('html');
```

and use html `meta` like this :

```
<?php

$meta = array(
        array(
                'name' => 'description',
                'content' => $seo_data[0]->META_DESCRIPTION
        ),
        array(
                'name' => 'keywords',
                'content' => $seo_data[0]->META_KEYWORDS
        ),
        array(
                'name' => 'url',
                'content' => $seo_data[0]->META_URL
        ),
        array(
                'name' => 'copyright',
                'content' => $seo_data[0]->META_COPYRIGHT
        )
);
echo meta($meta);
?>
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html#meta